# Await function to finish calling another API

Tags: node.js, async-await, request, azure-function-app

I am new to using async/await and having a couple issues.

I have the code below, which seems to not wait until the previous function is finished?

```
var url = require('url');
var path = require('path');
var https = require('https');
var request = require('request');
var url1 = 
var url2 = 
var url3 =


module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    var call = await callUrl(context, url1);
    context.log(call);
    var call2 = await callUrl(context, url2);
    context.log(call2);
    var call3 = await callUrl(context, url3);
    context.log(call3);
};

function callUrl (context, web) {
    var requestUrl = url.parse(web);
    const requestOptions = {
        hostname: requestUrl.hostname,
        path: requestUrl.path,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };
    var request = https.request(requestOptions, function(res) {
        var data = "";
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            data += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function () {
            var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
            return jsonData;
        });        
    }).on('error', function(error) {
        context.log("request error:", error);
        return context.done();
    });
    request.end();
}
```

I am trying to get `call` to happen, then when it is finished `call2`, then when that is finished `call3`.

Can someone pinpoint why this does not occur? Currently, it hits all 3 pretty much asap, and each `context.log` is `undefined` presumably because the endpoints don't return anything. Each `url` is another azure function app API I have created.

There is nothing I am requiring to return from each `call` to use, I simply want them to finish before moving on the the next function.

Comment: Why are you doing a POST, but not sending any data with it?  And, why are you setting `Content-Type` when there is no content you are sending?  This seems like it should be a GET if you're just retrieving content.

Comment: I'd recommend using a pre-built library that does everything your `callUrl()` function does including parse the JSON response automatically for you.  My favorite is `got()`, but there's also node-fetch, superagent and axios that are all popular.  This is a regular programming need and many well-tested libraries have been built to do this for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your  `callUrl` method, which you call with `await`, needs to be either async itself or return a Promise. Why? because the work it does is itself asynchronous.

Here's your function adapted to use a Promise and return its actual value via the `resolve()` callback.

```
function callUrl (context, web) {
  var requestUrl = url.parse(web);
  const requestOptions = {
    hostname: requestUrl.hostname,
    path: requestUrl.path,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  };
  return new Promise(function (resolve,reject) {
    var request = https.request( requestOptions, function( res ) {
      var data = "";
      res.on( 'data', function( chunk ) {
        data += chunk;
      } );
      res.on( 'end', function() {
        var jsonData = JSON.parse( data );
        resolve( jsonData );
      } );
    } )
    .on( 'error', function( error ) {
      reject(error);
    } );
    request.end();
  });
}
```

Notice that you use a POST operation with no body. That's a little unconventional.

Comment: ah, n00b behaviour. Thanks! What would you recommend doing instead of POST with no body? I just need to call it, I don't need to send anything. Also, what would be the async solution without returning a promise?

Comment: Either you put the Promise in it, or you use a library that wires up the state machine for you, like `axios`. With that, it returns a Promise, so you can await it.

Comment: You could use a GET if the service you call supports it.  There's nothing *wrong* with a bodyless POST, it's just slightly strange. If you keep the bodyless POST, you might put a comment about it in there so the next person to work on your code understands.

Comment: npm has packages called `request-promise` and `node-fetch`, both of which can give you ways to hit web services without writing the Promise stuff yourself. But, why?  `await` and `Promise.next()` use precisely the same mechanism.